# Programmatically enable or disable Assertion in TestNG

Tags: java, testing, selenium-webdriver, testng

Usually when we run testcases using TestNG, assertion error stops further execution after that point. But, sometimes it would be better if we could run the whole script. Manually blocking/disabling those assertions become tedious process. Hence, if there were some ways to programmatically enable/disable assertions other than manual it would be of great help indeed.

Does TestNG support this? If not, can anyone help me please?

Comment: Did you try SoftAssert? http://beust.com/weblog/2012/07/29/reinventing-assertions/

Comment: Nope, I need to use assertion. But, for some reason I want to enable/disable those assertions as needed.

Comment: SoftAssert is assertion but it will check all assertions once and you can avoid the check if you want. Otherwise, you can use a 3rd party assertion lib (but I don't know if one exists) or make yours.

Comment: Thanks @JulienHerr

Answer (score 1):

As Julien mentioned above you are better off making a custom softAssert of your own. I don't know, I could be horribly wrong but the standard softAssert that comes with testNG didn't give me the behaviour that I was after.

I suppose the most common reason that your tests are failing is an ElementNotFound or TimeOutException. So in your waitForElement method you can capture these exceptions (or any exception for that matter) and print a warning msg on the console (or don't print anything or even take a screenshot if you might, like a warning error but not a show-stopper error). Something like the below:

```
 public boolean waitForElement(String elementName, int timeOut) {

   try{
elementPresent=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(findXpath(elementName)))).isDisplayed());

  }                             
  catch(org.openqa.selenium.TimeOutException e1){e1.printStackTrace();elementPresent=false;takeScreenshot();}       
  }     

  return elementPresent;   
}
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Using [QAF Validation](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/assertion_verification.html) you can fulfill your requirements, for selenium it provides inbuilt verification methods, if it fails then testcase also continues to execution.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested , SoftAssert can be used which does not halt execution even if assertion fails.
Also enable/disable assertions is possible by flagging tests as enabled=false or enabled=true. This is in turn runs all tests [and thereby assertions] except those are marked as enabled=false

Example. Assertion in example won't be executed as test is disabled.

```
       @Test (enabled=false)                           
       public void verifySearchReport {
       soft.assertEquals("About*", "About123Soft","FAILED ASSERT");
       soft.assertAll();
        }
```

Assertion in example will be executed as test is enabled. Further execution of tests won't be halted [Even if assertion is failing] as SoftAssert is used.

```
       @Test (enabled=true)                           
       public void verifySearchReport {
       soft.assertEquals("About*", "About123Soft","FAILED ASSERT");
       soft.assertAll();
        }
        //Further @Test here
```